# Using Chai with Jest and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, chai

I'm trying to use Chai expect library while running Jest with TypeScript but I'm not able to.

What I'm actually trying to do is something similar to [this](https://medium.com/@RubenOostinga/combining-chai-and-jest-matchers-d12d1ffd0303).

But I'm having no luck achieving this with TypeScript.

Can someone give me any directions to this this with TS while having autocomplete and no type errors working?

I'm using `ts-jest`.

Comment: What is the specific error you are running into? Are you using [`ts-jest`](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest)?

Comment: @ExplosionPills edited to say that I'm using `ts-jest`. When I try to access `global.expect` within the test folder, it says that global don't have type `expect`!

Comment: Can you just use `expect` instead of `global.expect`? You should also have `@types/jest` installed as a (dev) dependency

Comment: I do have `@types/jest` installed. I also can use expect alone, but I can’t reassign to it like that medium post, to include chai expects in it!

Comment: You actually may not need chai. I think jest covers pretty much all of the assertions you would use it for. Can you just use `chai.expect` where you need it? If worse comes to worst you could also use `declare const global: any`

Comment: @ExplosionPills it was more because I like chai syntax and something like checking types is simple, but I sure can use chai can without this. It’s just syntax sugar :D

Answer (score 2):

I finally gave up and just "import { expect } from chai;" in my spec files.